# How to get JSONModel in a controller SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have created a JSON data & saved in webapp/json/TableData.json & in manifest.json, I have added following code : -

```
"BPCdata" : {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
    "uri": "json/TableData.json"
},
```

How can I get this model in a controller?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the model with the following code. It works !!. Thanks for the responses.

`var bpcCollect  = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("BPCdata").getProperty("/BPC");`

Answer (score 1):

Pass name of the model to be obtained as argument to [getModel()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getModel)

```
this.getView().getModel("BPCdata");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `sap.ui.getCore().getModel()`

Reference : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html#getModel

Comment: This answer is wrong. When a manifest is used, the model will be bound to the Component, which is hierarchically higher than core. Because of that, you won't find it in core.